# how to re-order a list based on another one that has the same items in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, data-structures

I have two list with the same items in both of them. I want to sort the second `unordered` list based on the ordering of the first one.

```
ordered_list = ["first_name", "last_name", "language", "gender", "country", ]

unordered_list = ["country", "gender", "first_name", "last_name", "language",] 

unordered_list.sort(key=ordered_list)

print(unordered_list)
```

PS: I have a looooonger list to work with, this is just an example.

GOAL: the `unordered_list` items need to be sorted exactly how items are ordered in `ordered_list`

Is there a better approach than the one above that doesn't work?

Comment: So the unordered list will become ordered and the ordered list will become unordered?

Comment: @Mike67 the `unordered_list` has to be sorted exactly how elements are ordered in `ordered_list`. we dont modify `ordered_list`

Comment: Why not just make a copy of the `ordered_list`?

Comment: Are all the values in the `unordered_list` in the `ordered_list`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the index as the key:

```
ordered_list = ["first_name", "last_name", "language", "gender", "country", ]

unordered_list = ["country", "gender", "first_name", "last_name", "language",] 

unordered_list.sort(key= lambda x: ordered_list.index(x))

print(unordered_list)
```

Output

```
['first_name', 'last_name', 'language', 'gender', 'country']
```